# ASP.net MVC: Return to another view and show the new url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a complete beginner when it comes to ASP.net MVC and I don't work with models yet. This is just a test project.

I have created a simple form in a view called Index. In here the user is supposed to write their name and then it directs the user to a Start view in which their name is displayed, the name is saved using sessions.

This first method just checks if the user has written their name and directs the user to the Start view if a name session variable already exists.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
        string username = form["Username"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Field can not be empty";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Session["Username"] = username;
            return View("Start");
        }

    }
```

The next method just checks again if the name has been set, and if so the name is displayed.

```
    public ActionResult Start()
    {
        if ((Session["Username"]) == null)
        {
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.User = Session["Username"].ToString();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

It all works fine when the URLs are correct, like when I type in Home/Start myself after a name has been saved. But just returning the Start view just says "Welcome !" with just a space where the name should have been.

This is all within the same controller.

I am noticing that returning a view does not change the url to the new one. I am assuming that is the reason it fails. I have been searching for a while with no success, though I suspect it's very simple... I have to use sessions though. How can I make this work?

Comment: You do not use `return View("Start");` - you redirect to the `Start` method - `return RedirectToAction("Start");`

Comment: Ahh, thank you! @StephenMuecke